# Change padding on RowsSupportFragment

Tags: android, leanback

I tried to combine leanback with xml, but I had some problem - padding the leanback row is different from padding other elements. How can I change padding to RowsSupportFragment?
[image]

In xml

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/tags_container"
        android:layout_below="@+id/guidance_icon"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"/>
```

And in java code

```
RelativeLayout tags = view.findViewById(R.id.tags_container);
            ScreenshotFragment = FragmentScreenshots.newInstance(mFilm);
            getChildFragmentManager()
                    .beginTransaction()
                    .replace(tags.getId(), ScreenshotFragment)
                    .commit();
```

class FragmentScreenshots

```
public static class FragmentScreenshots extends RowsSupportFragment {
    private Film mFilm = null;

    public static FragmentScreenshots newInstance(Film film) {
        FragmentScreenshots fragment = new FragmentScreenshots();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putSerializable(ActivityFilm.PARAM_FILM, film);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ListRowPresenter presenter = new CompatibleListRowPresenter(false, false, true);
        ArrayObjectAdapter mRowsAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(presenter);
        List<AbstractCard> list = new ArrayList<>();
        setAdapter(mRowsAdapter);

        ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found where I can edit the padding on RowsSupportFragment.

In your activity theme add the item

```
<item name="rowHorizontalGridStyle">@style/CustomHorizontalGridView</item>
```

And in **CustomHorizontalGridView** u can edit padding

```
<style name="CustomHorizontalGridView">
    <item name="android:focusable">true</item>
    <item name="android:focusableInTouchMode">true</item>

    <item name="android:paddingStart">@dimen/your_padding</item>
    <item name="android:paddingEnd">@dimen/your_padding</item>

    <item name="android:paddingBottom">@dimen/lb_browse_item_vertical_spacing</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">@dimen/lb_browse_item_vertical_spacing</item>
    <item name="android:horizontalSpacing">@dimen/lb_browse_item_horizontal_spacing</item>
    <item name="android:verticalSpacing">@dimen/lb_browse_item_vertical_spacing</item>
    <item name="focusOutFront">true</item>
</style>
```

Comment: If I can give you more than +1 , I would do it, thanks as lot! Just one minor thing though:  there is a small mistake in the xml code HorizontalGridView should be CustomHorizontalGridView